# Is there a way to only count number of nonzeo elements between zeros in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to count number of nonzero elements between zeros in a list.

This is my list

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0]
```

Desired output:

```
a = [1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Hi! So, how far have you gotten with this? We're here to help you solve this yourself, but we can't wildly guess where you're stuck in your own approach, how much Python you already understand and what's hindering you with your current knowledge. Without showing what you've tried, this is simply *too broad to be answered*.

Comment: I've also removed the [tag:numpy] tag, as your question is not using numpy! If your current approach involves NumPy, please **edit** your question with an extensive description of your approach and add back the tag again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

out = [len(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(a, lambda x: x!=0) if k]
```

output: `[1, 3, 2]`

how it works:

- for each group of consecutive non-zero or zero item (`lambda x: x!=0` sets the group key as `True` for non-zeros)
- if the key is `True`, get the length of the group

Comment: Nice use of `groupby` and leverage the `key` changes to form new group. It'll be helpful to elaborate that for the beginners.

Answer (score 1):

By using simple logic

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0]
l=[]
c=0
for i in a:
    if i!=0:
        c=c+1
    else:
        if c!=0:
            l.append(c)
            c=0
print(l)
```

output :

```
[1, 3, 2]
```